# How to install MobileTerminal on a non-jailbreak iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I downloaded MobileTerminal sources from http://mobileterminal.googlecode.com/svn.

I compiled it and it works perfect on iOS simulator.When run on iPhone, there is an alert said "Not allowed to fork from inside Sandbox".

The author of MobileTerminal said that it will work fine if put the MobileTerminal's binary in /Applications,but how to do this on a non-jailbreak iPhone? My iPhone is running on iOS5.1.
Special thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place binaries in `./Applications` on a non jailbroken iPhone.
Thus this app will only work on Jailbroken iPhones.

Also all apps on non Jailbroken iphone are placed in a sandbox and can only access files with this sandbox. Thus you can't leave the apps sandbox.

Comment: Thanks.And I have to jailbreak my phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Putty and iFun-box
2. Go into iFun-box and go to tools then in USB tunnel
3. Copy the address of pc
4. Enter Putty put the address

Type: `su`

Type in your password, in order to get root access, default is: alpine *(fyi, you won't see the characters you are typing)*

Type: `cp -R /var/mobile/Media/Books/lib /var` *(fyi, be sure to note the space, mind Capitals!)*
[7b.] ONLY if you are getting: 'missing var/log/apt' error:

Type: `su` and password *(if you closed Terminal before)*

Type: `mkdir /var/log/apt` 
[7c.] ONLY if you are getting: 'trying to overwrite /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries' error:

Type: `su` and password *(if you closed Terminal before)*

Type: `cd /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries` *(fyi, if folder doesn't seem to exist: do step 8 first!)*

Type: `ls -1` *(fyi, you should see 2 files now: one of them should be 'DynamicLibraries')*

Type: `rm DynamicLibraries`
[ 8. ] Open Cydia now. Install a simple tweak (it doesn't matter which one, but iCleaner is a good choice), in order to create the directory: `/var/stash`

Alternatively, you can also use Terminal to do it:

Type: `su` and password *(if you closed Terminal before)*

Type: `mkdir /var/stash`